# Fetch MS Access Data Using C# in Table or Formatted Form

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I am bit new on c# Window application Development, i have developed lots of working applications in c#, and now i am working on Database using MS Access ODBC. I get success in data insertion into Database but now i am fetching the data, and facing issue of not getting data into the form.

So please can anybody let me know the best way to fetch Data from MS Access Database using c# in an proper table form.

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider;" + @"Data source= C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\bin\debug\Database21.accdb";

        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM newdb2";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();

                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())


                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    reddd.Text = reader.GetString(0).ToString();
                    reddf.Text = reader.GetString(1).ToString();

                    // Insert code to process data.

                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
        }
```

Comment: is there any error you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is right? Did you use this select in your access file? Debug your code and check your variables.

Comment: Connection is perfect, actully when i am using MessageBox.Show(GetString(1)); Data is poping up perfectly. But not displaying in form page.

Comment: @sandeepsingh You try to show as `MessageBox.Show(reddf.Text);` instead?

Comment: What is type or mode of these texboxes ?

Comment: These are actually labels i am using. I am just eager to learn a way to get all data in table format.